# Tensorflow core

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, python-3.5

I run the code below on Tensorflow 1.0 using python 3.5

```
a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
adder_node = a + b  # + provides a shortcut for tf.add(a, b)
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(adder_node, {a: 3, b: 4.5}))
print(sess.run(adder_node, {a: [1, 3], b: [2, 4]}))
```

I got this error

> > > print(sess.run(adder_node, {a:3, b:4.5}))
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1068, in _run
> > >           allow_operation=False)
> > >         File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2708, in as_graph_element
> > >           return self._as_graph_element_locked(obj, allow_tensor, allow_operation)
> > >         File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2787, in _as_graph_element_locked
> > >           raise ValueError("Tensor %s is not an element of this graph." % obj)
> > >       ValueError: Tensor Tensor("Placeholder_3:0", dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 895, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1071, in _run
    + e.args[0])
TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Tensor Tensor("Placeholder_3:0", dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.

> > >

Please help me debug this, not too sure where the error is coming from

Comment: This is not your complete code (sess is undefined), so please make a complete example that we can try.

Comment: sess =  variable for running the computational graph in a session @MatiasValdenegro

Comment: I know what a session is, that's not the point. The problem is that we cannot run your code as it is.

Comment: OK, now I see the new code, I ran it and it works without issues in TensorFlow 1.3

Comment: This doesn't seem to be your full code, the error means that there is a node that is part of the current graph. The current code is not sufficient to reproduce.

Comment: I fixed it now, there was a syntax error in what i run. The script works fine.